# how to Building Custom Event Receivers in WSO2 CEP 4.1.0

Tags: java, eclipse, events, wso2, manifest

I wrote a custom event adapter and I built the jar file. I have placed the jar file in the dropins folder and restarted the CEP engine, but it appears within the event adapter.

The reference url is:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Building+Custom+Event+Receivers#BuildingCustomEventReceivers-ExposingCustomEventReceiverasanOSGIService

but it is not explained in the OSGI bundle.

My MANIFEST.MF is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1

Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_92

Built-By: wso2-builder

Bundle-Description: org.wso2.event.adaptor.test

Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2

Bundle-Name: org.wso2.event.adaptor.test

Bundle-SymbolicName: org.wso2.event.adaptor.test

Bundle-Vendor: WSO2

Bundle-Version: 5.0.10

Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin

DynamicImport-Package: *

Private-Package: org.wso2.event.adaptor.test.internal, org.wso2.event.adaptor.test.internal.*

Export-Package:  !org.wso2.event.adaptor.test.internal, !org.wso2.event.adaptor.test.internal.*, org.wso2.event.adaptor.test.*,

Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.core, org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.core.*, !javax.xml.namespace, javax.xml.namespace; version=0.0.0, *;resolution:=optional,

Service-Component: OSGI-INF/serviceComponents.xml

Tool: Bnd-1.43.0
```

Comment: Did you mean appear or doesn't appear? How did you build the jar? Did you use maven bundle plugin to build the osgi bundle?

Comment: Oh! it means disappeared. and I`m use to plug-in-project in eclipse. no use maven bundle.